# Importing selective rows from JSON to Google Sheets and avg

Tags: google-sheets, import

I would like to import two rows from JSON into a Google Sheet.

The JSON is structured like this:

{"type":"A","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"countA":27,"name":"NameA","countB":2},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","id":"65"}

I have thousands of rows like this.

I would need it to return all "countA" as well as all "countB" rows.

Comment: The JSON is incomplete as it has an opening bracket `[` but hasn't a closing bracket `]`, by thee other hand, it doesn't include any mention of a search of research made regarding this.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you look up on Async

here is the function that is working in my buy pulling all data from json and displaying in a text view.

```
 public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            //   JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            //   JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("");
            JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finalJson);

            StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String t1 = finalObject.getString("ib_itemcode1");
                String t2 = finalObject.getString("transtatuscode");
                String t3 = finalObject.getString("invtid");
                String t4 = finalObject.getString("descr");

                // int year = finalObject.getInt("transtatuscode");


                finalBufferedData.append(t1 + " - " + t2 + " - " + t3 + " - " + t4 + "\n");
            }
            //JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
            return finalBufferedData.toString();

            //return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

take note in the finalobject.toString part, it is where i change from data to string.

i am new to this too, almost as fresh as you. But we can work and learn together.

Comment: Have you tried this on Google Sheets?